# is vue-storefront support (nuxtjs with typescript)?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-storefront, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use @storefront-ui/nuxt  inside a nuxtjs (with typescript)  project.

but this error show for me
Could not find a declaration file for module '@storefront-ui/nuxt'. 'c:/Users/user/Desktop/testnuxt/node_modules/@storefront-ui/nuxt/lib/module.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/storefront-ui__nuxt` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@storefront-ui/nuxt';`Vetur(7016)

and this error doesnet appear if i used the nuxtjs (with javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To use Vue Storefront you need to use one template that is recommended by your integration.

You can check on the available integrations at https://docs.vuestorefront.io/v2/integrations/